# Difference among these sentences

Tags: grammar, giving-and-receiving

> **前田は僕に辞書をあげた。**
> **前田は僕に辞書をくれた。**
> **前田は僕に辞書をやりました。**
> Maeda gave me a dictionary.

These sentences have the same meaning. The first sentence used "ageta" as a verb, the second used "kureta", and the third used "yarimashita". What is the difference between these sentences? Are all of these sentences correct?

Comment: Only number two is correct

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/260/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69801/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/45322/9831

Answer (score 1):

Having an understanding of the 上下関係 and うちそと in Japanese culture might make this easier to understand.

There will always be exceptions but a simple way of thinking about it is:

- くれる if you are the receiver. This is also true if the receiver is someone from your うち and the giver is from your そと (like a family friend giving something to your kid).
- やる emphasizes the lower status of the receiver. So it's usually used if the receiver is an animal, or if used as an accessory verb, to make it especially humble.
- あげる for all other cases.